# Combine two ActiveRecord::Relation with OR, not AND, returning a Relation and not an Array to be able to paginate later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, will-paginate, relation

`a` and `b` are ActiveRecord::Relation objects which return the same type of objects(Micropost objects in this case)

```
a.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
b.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
a.first
=> Micropost(...) 
b.first
=> Micropost(...) #They both return the same type of objects
c=a+b
c.class
=> Array #This is not what i'm looking for
c=a|b
c.class
=> Array #Not what i'm looking for either
c=(a or b)
c.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation #But it is just a, so it's wrong
c==a
=> true
a.merge(b)
=> []  #It merges with AND which in my case results in an empty array
```

Is there some way to "OR" both Relation objects and return another Relation object in Rails 3.2.11? Do I need to use some gem such as `squeel` to do it?

If it can't be done: Why it can't be done? Can I paginate the array resulting from `a|b` without loading every record from the database?
If it can be done: Could anyone please write an example of how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I copied the wrong variables into the block of code, b was not an ActiveRecord::Relation, it was actually an array and that is why a.merge(b) returned [].
My fault.

TLDR: Question is wrong, and array can be paginated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you question: `Can I paginate the array resulting from a|b without loading every record from the database?`

**Yes**, you can paginate `array`. Only you need to do is `require 'will_paginate/array'` file where your are using `paginate` for `array`. If you are using in many place then its better to add it in `config/initializers`. And its array so it won't load every record from database each time (i.e.) query is fired only once. To load association you can use `eager load on array` using `include`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer!. One more question, paginate on a Relation object is loading 30 objects from the database each page. If I do `c=a|b` and paginate that array, it will load all the records at once from the database into an array and then show 30 of them for each page. If the number of records is very high it could be a problem.Should I do something like `c=a.limit(200).offset(@page*30)|b.limit(200).offset(@page*30)` to avoid that? Would something like that work and is that the easier way to do it?

Comment: One thing I am not clear why are you getting `same active relations` in two different object and combining them?? Why don't you write single query to get results??

Comment: One of them is returned from a function with a where query(User.feed function), the other one is returned through an association(User.mentioned_in where mentioned_in is an association defined by: has_many :mentioned_in, through: :mention_relationships, source: :post etc.), the two relation objects are not the same. To write a single query i'd have to write the query for the association too and join them. I guess in the end i'll have to do it that way, but I thought there could be another(better) way to do it without changing much code.

Comment: In both case you have only `objects`, right? Then `a.merge(b)` should return `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Why is in your case its empty?

Comment: My fault sorry, you are right, I don't know why I thought that b(which in my case is User.mentioned_in) was an ActiveRecord::Relation but it wasn't, `User.mentioned_in` seems to return an Array. When I wrote the question I was testing everything in the rails console but I must have copied the wrong variables. Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Yes I know that with an array I can't do anything more than convert the other one to array and combine them. I'm going to edit the question to let people know that there is an error in the question so that it doesn't mislead anyone and accept your answer. Thanks!