# "Append" two different ActiveRecord::Relation into a single ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am in a similar situation as in [ICTylor's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054524/combine-two-activerecordrelation-with-or-not-and-returning-a-relation-and-no).

So I have:

```rb
user1=User.find(1);
user2=User.find(2);
written=Micropost.where("user_id=2");
written.class #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
written.length   #=> 50
replied=Micropost.where("response = 2 ")  #=> 1
replied.class #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Now if I:

```rb
alltogether= written + replied;
alltogether.class #=> Array
alltogether.length #=> 51
```

However I would like something that would be equivalent to doing:

```rb
all_sql= Micropost.where("user_id = 2  OR response = 2")
all_sql.class #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
all_sql.length #=> 51
```

**In other words** I would like to somehow *append* the records found by one `Micropost.where(...)` to the ones found by the other `Micropost.where(...)` into an **ActiveRecord::Relation** object. Resulting in an equivalent of **all_sql** but reached in two steps.

**A bit of explanation**. This part of the application is designed to provide a *twitter-like* functionality for reply messages.

**E.g.**: When the user with `User.id = 1` sends this message to `User.id=2`:

`@2: hey this is a reply.`

The application will create a `Micropost` with the following parameters:

`@post= Micropost.create(user:1, content:"@2: hey this is a reply", response: 2)`

So `response` simply indicates the *receiver* id of the reply. In the case when the message is not of reply-type, then `response = nil`.

Following this idea, I would like to be able to:

```rb
def replies_to(user)
  Micropost.where("response = #{user.id}")
end

def written_posts_by(user)
  Micropost.where("user_id = #{user.id}")
end

def interesting_posts(user)
  replies= replies_to(user)
  written= written_posts_by(user)
  #And now the question arises!

  new_relation= replies union written#<---How can I do this!?
end
```

Comment: The where(... OR ...) method would be the more efficient way to do this. Is there a reason for not doing that?

Comment: That's just it! I want this filtering clearly separated in two diferent methods, e.g. `replies_to(user)`, `written_posts_by(user)`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what is "replied" and what is "response = 2"? What does this "2" mean? post id or user id or else?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it indeed, needed clarification. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design itself has some problems, say what if a post replied to two or more receivers? Also there will be too much null data in table which is not good.

Anyway, based current design allowing one receiver only, some changes is necessary at model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :replies, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: 'response_id'

  def written_posts
    posts
  end

  def posts_replied_to_me
    replies
  end
end
```

Notes of the above changes:

1. The APIs are better in User table so they don't need arguments like `(user)`
2. With association, the above two public methods are actually unnecessary and for present purpose only. You can access these posts directly from association API.

Now for the `interesting_posts`. Due to the above refactoring you no longer rely the above method to build an aggregated query as they have different structure. Patching as Mori mentioned is a solution but I myself prefer not to touch libs' if possible.

I would prefer a method to aggregate the queries dedicated to this case.

```
def interested_posts
  Post.where(interesting_criteria)
end

private
def interesting_criteria
  conditions = []
  conditions << written_by_me
  conditions << replied_to_me
  conditions << foo_bar
  conditions.join(' AND ')
end

def written_by_me
  "user_id = #{self.id}"
end

def replied_to_me
  "response_id = #{self.id}"
end

def foo_bar
  "feel free to add more"
end
```

Comment: Billy Chan: That is a really constructive comment, thank you for that. The refactoring does make a lot of sense in the case of one-reciever replies. In order to have *multiple-receiver* replies, what if I say that `Micropost` `has_many receivers, class_name:'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'`. However, I am not sure that the **circular** nature of these associations (i.e., Micropost has receivers > User has microposts) is very recommended.

Comment: Also, with regard to the external module/lib vs specific method to aggregate the query: isn't it more "portable"/flexible/easy to maintain just coding a module and extending the desired class with it? Is there a solid tecnhical reason to prefer writing a method rather than importing a `module`, or is it just personal choice?

Comment: @vint-i-vuit, for multiple replies, or actually "mentions", it is another many to many relationship between User and Post. User has many "mentioned", and Post can mention many users. A join table will take care of this. Or you can check 'socialization' gem's as_as_mentionable part. For external libs, my point in answer is better not to touch/patch them within you code when you still have alternative solutions.

Comment: I will surely have a look at that gem, seems really useful. Although I will try to reach that functionality from scratch myself first.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/9hohaa) discusses this issue and offers a [patch](https://github.com/rails/arel/pull/118) to enable chainable unions in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Wow, I will need to look at that more carefully. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll have a look tomorrow and bring back feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way built-in Rails to do unions on ActiveRecord::Relation as of today . You're better off writing a query with OR even if it is not so DRY.

With arel:

```rb
def interesting_posts(user)
  posts = Micropost.arel_table
  Micropost.where(posts[:response].eq(user.id).or(posts[:user_id].eq(user.id)))
end
```

With SQL:

```
def interesting_posts(user)
  Micropost.where('response = ? OR user_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
end
```