# How to combine two ActiveRecord::Relation to form active relation under OR condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-relation

This link is [great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054524/combine-two-activerecordrelation-with-or-not-and-returning-a-relation-and-no) but it doesn't address the problem of getting an active_relation after combining two active relation under **or** condition. There are other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540801/combine-two-activerecordrelation-objects) as well but
none of them answer the above question. Although for `and`ing method `merge` works and gives active relation, my predicament in finding a way to `or` two condition.  To elucidate my problem, suppose I have to **or** two differently written query rather than performing separately and adding them which does not output active relation. 
For example:-

```
@incoming = Message.incoming_from_my_friends_only(@current_user) # where 'incoming_from_my_friends_only' is a active record query  
@outgoing = Message.outgoing_to_my_friends_only(@current_user) # same here
```

Now, I don't want to do this

```
@incoming = Message.incoming_from_my_friends_only(@current_user) 
@outgoing = Message.outgoing_to_my_friends_only(@current_user)

@messages = @incoming + @outgoing
```

Although doing this is not an issue, but I would rather have the result in active relation so that I can perform any further active record query.

Any ideas... or better work around for my problem??

Revised:-

I was looking at the profile and found that this question was bereft of any activity, not even a comment, even though it might prove to be question vital importance. I saying this because doing **and** on `AR` is very easy as shown in second link using **merge** method but no such method exist for **or** why is that??? shouldn't the pro of rails community provide this method???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found a way to combine two active relation under **or** condition but not the answer I was looking for like- there is method for performing **and** on active relation using [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540801/combine-two-activerecordrelation-objects). 
  Answer I found was this.

```
# replace the comment part in where by the condition written for incoming_from_my_friends_only and outgoing_to_my_friends_only respectively
@incoming = Message.where("(#incoming_from_my_friends_only(@current_user)) or (outgoing_to_my_friends_only(@current_user))")
```